Why is my WorkManager worker not being triggered in onDestroy?
I’m facing an issue with triggering a WorkManager worker from the onDestroy method of my MainActivity. Here's the scenario:
I’ve implemented a ClearCacheWorker using WorkManager to handle background tasks when the app is closed. I’m scheduling this worker in the onDestroy method like this:

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "onDestroy called");
    ClearCacheScheduler.scheduleClearCache(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}

The ClearCacheScheduler looks like this:
public class ClearCacheScheduler {
    public static void scheduleClearCache(Context context) {
        Log.d("ClearCacheScheduler", "scheduleClearCache called");
 

        OneTimeWorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(ClearCacheWorker.class)
            
            .setInitialDelay(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addTag("clear_cache")
            .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(request)
    }
}

However, when I close the app, the onDestroy method gets called (verified with logs), but the ClearCacheWorker's doWork() is never triggered. Here’s my worker implementation:

public class ClearCacheWorker extends Worker {
    private static final String TAG = "ClearCacheWorker";

    public ClearCacheWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.d(TAG, "doWork()");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(500); // Simulate delay
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doWork() interrupted");
            return Result.success();
        }

        if (isAppInForeground(getApplicationContext())) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doWork() App is in foreground");
            return Result.success();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "doWork() App is in background");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClearCacheService.class);
        intent.putExtras(new android.os.Bundle());
        getApplicationContext().startService(intent);

        return Result.success();
    }

    private boolean isAppInForeground(Context context) {
        android.app.ActivityManager activityManager =
            (android.app.ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        java.util.List<android.app.ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processes =
            activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (processes != null) {
            for (android.app.ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : processes) {
                if (processInfo.importance ==
                        android.app.ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND
                    && processInfo.processName.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "doWork() App in foreground");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "doWork() App in background");
        return false;
    }
}

I’ve checked that:

The onDestroy method logs properly when the app is closed.

The scheduleClearCache method is being triggered


Questions:

Is there a reason why WorkManager doesn’t launch the worker when called from onDestroy?

Could it be related to the app’s process being killed before WorkManager can enqueue or execute the work?

Would scheduling the worker in onStop or another lifecycle method be more reliable?


Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!

Have you tried scheduling a non-zero initial delay?

Yes, I've tried but still not triggering the doWork

If I'm not mistaken, when an app is being destroyed, there's no guarantee that WorkManager tasks scheduled during onDestroy() will execute, as the process may be terminated before WorkManager can properly initialize and execute the work request.
I believe that moving the logic into the onStop() lifecycle method may be a better alternative, since it could provide your app with more time to submit the worker to the workers' database. The onStop() I believe is called when the app is no longer visible to the user but before its destruction by the system.
Others can chime in on this if I'm wrong and I'll happily edit my answer.

I believe the issue is related to the fact that you use Activity context to create your WorkManager. And than you kill your Activity right after creating WorkManager and scheduling the job.
Try to replace it with Application context:
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "onDestroy called");
    ClearCacheScheduler.scheduleClearCache(this.getApplicationContext());
    super.onDestroy();
}

In general it would be a better idea to create your WorkManager instance in Dagger's Component provide-method and use scoped context there, but in your case using application context might fix the problem.
Also if you decide to create a specific worker object for your operations, consider that it's important to pass context directly to your custom worker constructor.

I tried your solution, but still having the same issue
